# Why is it “sponsern” and not “sponsorn”?

Tags: inflection, anglicism

The noun is *Sponsor* and not *Sponser,* so why is it *sponsern* and not *sponsorn?* Is this because *Sponsor* is an anglicism? Are there other examples of such strange flexions in the German language?

Comment: You should note that infinitives in German (except for "tun" and "sein") end in "-en", "-eln" or "-ern". "-orn" is not a valid infinitive ending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer to your question: yes this is because [*sponsern*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sponsern) is an anglicism.

See also [Korrekturen.de on this](http://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/sponsorn.shtml).

As for your second question, whether there are similar examples, I’d say pretty much every word that is taken from English is a potential candidate. This depends on how “correctly” the verb was taken into the German language.

An example: the verb *to download* is by now also widely used in Germany in the form *etwas downloaden*. As you can see, the usual verb ending *-en* was attached. Now in the case of *sponsern,* it seems that people found it more convenient to use *sponsern* instead of the correct form [sponsoren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sponsoren). However, the form *sponsoren* also exists.

So the verb *sponsern* is merely an abbreviation of the correct form *sponsoren* but over the years this, initially incorrect, version found its ways into German dictionaries.

Comment: Maybe you should note that the "e" in "sponsoren" is skipped and the second "o" is lightened to "e" so as to match the pattern of verbs like "klingeln, verberssern ..." and so on. Otherwise people might think that the "o" was skipped.

Comment: There is the word "herumdoktern" (to meddle with sth.) that comes from the "Doktor". Regarding its German shape with a prefixed particle and the fact that there is no idiomatic verb "to doctor around/along" in English, I don't think that "herumdoktern" is an anglicism. Any explanation for "sponsern" instead of "-orn" must also explain "herumdoktern" instead of "-orn". Therefore, I don't think that the fact that "sponsern" is an anglicism is the reason for its spelling with "e" rather than "o".

Comment: I can't think of a German infinitive with the ending -orn. It doesn't fit into the system of German infinitive-endings.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we have a word **Sponsor/to sponsor** (the German noun or the English verb; it does not matter) and want to derive a German verb from it.

Let's have a little look at the history of the word **sponsor**. It is a *nomen agentis* derived from the latin verb **spondere**. *Nomina agentis* can be formed by suffixing **-tor** to the verbal root (**spond-**). Two contacting dental plosives (i.e. "d" and "t") yielded an "s"; so the *nomen agentis* ending becomes **-sor** and we have **sponsor** containing the modified root **spons-**.

Potentially, the German verb can be derived from the roots **spons-** or **spond-** or the full word **sponsor**. The average German speaker cannot know the above etymology. Thus, if the verb **spondere** is not loaned parallelly into German he/she cannot know that there was a "d" in the root. The German verb we want to derive must contain an "s". Now there are several possibilities to form a verb: The verb must end in **-en**, **-ern** or **-eln**; the verb may end in **-ieren** but it need not. The **-eln** can be excluded because there is no "l" in the last syllable of **sponsor**.

- If the "d" of the root were known, it would be possible to form a verb **spondieren**. Actually, there *is* such a [verb](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spondieren) and it is related to latin *spondere*. However, it has a totally different meaning from "to sponsor" and does not come from English but directly from Latin into German.
- Another possibility is **sponsieren**; again, this verb exists - but again with a totally different [meaning](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sponsieren).
- As somebody mentioned before, the verb **sponsoren** [exists](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sponsoren), too. It is derived from English *to sponsor*.
- Finally, another possibility is **sponsern**, the [main variant](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sponsern) of the verb that is derived from English *to sponsor*.

Now, why did **sponsern** win and **sponsoren** lose, i.e. why is **sponsern** so common? - The answer lies in German word stress: German prefers *Trochee* words. Those are words with the main stress on the first (root) syllable and an unstressed Schwa-sound in the second (inflection suffix) syllable. *Trochee* is the typical German meter; most German nouns/verbs have two syllables and follow this structure (e.g. *die Wolke*, *die Wolken*) and often nouns with only one syllable form plurals with a Trochee structure (e.g. *die Frau*, *die Frauen*). **sponsern** follows the Trochee structure, **sponsoren** does not; that's why **sponsern** won.

N.B.: The reason why **sponsern** dominates **sponsoren** must lie in German itself and not in the fact that **sponsern** came from English. This gets clear if you consider the verb **herumdoktern** that is derived from the noun *Doktor* and not a loanword. **-doktern** follows the Trochee principle, **-doktoren** would not.

Answer (score 0):

The ending -or is used to indicate a person or a thing doing something. A Sponsor, Prediktor + Korrektor in mathematics, Indikator, Rektor, Reaktor and many others. The Prediktor doesn't predictor, it predicts. The Indikator doesn't indicator, it indicates. So when turning a noun ending in -or into a verb, it is quite natural to remove the -or.

Comment: So the verb should be "to spons" and "sponsen"? - Actually, the "t" belongs to the agent-noun ending. "Sponsor" has an "s" instead of a "t" because its latin verb, "spondere", had a "d" and two touching dental plosives (-dt-) yielded an "s".